# Why don't we measure mass of oxygen used in the calorimeter

Tags: experimental-chemistry, enthalpy

> The apparatus shown in the diagram can be used to measure the enthalpy change of formation of magnesium oxide (MgO).
> [image]
> List the measurements you would need to make using this apparatus in order to calculate the enthalpy change of formation of magnesium oxide (MgO).

And the mark scheme said:

> Measurements needed:
>
> - volume/mass/weight of water (in the calorimeter)
> - initial + final temperature/temperature change/temperature rise (of the water)
> - mass of Mg (used)/mass MgO
> - (Not volume/moles/mass of oxygen used)

Why shouldn't I measure the mass of oxygen? Oxygen is also the reactant in its standard state as same as the magnesium element, isn't it?

Comment: Hint: what is the heat capacity of the water in the system and that of the oxygen? (Hint to the hint: calculate the moles each of water and oxygen then look up their molar heat capacities on Wikipedia).

Comment: Thx:) but i can still measure the mass of Mg used in order to find the MgO mass(mole) produced, right? Can I do the same for oxygen instead of Mg to find the mass(mole) of MgO?

Comment: Well, if I understand the comment, yes, you should measure the masses of Mg & MgO gravimetrically. If you had a way of measuring the O in MgO or measuring the amount of $\ce{O2}$ before and after the experiment then you could do that too, in theory. But in reality you do not. The whole point of the hints in my first post was to lead you to an estimation of how much more thermal mass of water you have in your system compared to that of oxygen in your system. Is that of oxygen small enough compared to water to be negligible? Are the Mg and MgO masses even used in that part of your calculations?

Comment: @airhuff Sorry>< That's my fault. I thought it was the standard enthalpy change (enthalpy change per mole) instead of enthalpy change of formation. So, the Mg and MgO masses are not necessary. Thank you^^

Comment: I'm not sure that I get that explanation, but hey, so longs as you do I guess all is good ;) Do note that in your procedure it says you need the masses of Mg and MgO; they are just not considered as part of the heat capacity of the system. The thermal mass of oxygen is just so small compared to that of the water that it is negligible.